# LARAVEL - show name of the user when logged in

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have made a login page 'admin-login' which redirected to a page 'admin' when authenticated. I want to display the name of the logged in user on the 'admin' page.

Have a look at my code:
Controller:

```
public function login(Request $req) {
    $email = $req->input('email');
    $password = $req->input('password');

    $checkLogin = DB::table('admin')->where(['email'=>$email,'password'=>$password])->get();

    if(count($checkLogin) > 0) {
        return view('admin')->with(['name'=>" "]);
    }

    else {
       // echo "Login Failed!";
       return Redirect::route('admin-login')->with(['error'=> "Invalid email or Password!!"]);
    }
}
```

I don't know what to write here 'with(['name'=>" "]);'. Plz help me out.

View:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <!-- Authentication Links -->
    @guest
        <li><a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a></li>
    @else
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true">
                {{ Session::get('name') }} <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get the currently authenticated user via `Auth::user()`

And his name like

`Auth::user()->name`;

Answer (score 3):

if you using laravel default auth model you can simply use **{{Auth::user()->name}}** it will print the name of the logedin user.

Comment: The session is working fine. problem is with the '@guest-else' tag in the view page.

Comment: first check the user using if(Auth::check()){ echo Auth::user()->name}else{ echo "guest name"}

Answer (score 2):

try using the below code :

```
public function login(Request $req) {
    $email = $req->input('email');
    $password = $req->input('password');

    $checkLogin = DB::table('admin')->where(['email'=>$email,'password'=>$password])->first();

    if(count($checkLogin) > 0) {
        return view('admin')->with(['name'=>$checkLogin->name]);
    }

    else {
       // echo "Login Failed!";
       return Redirect::route('admin-login')->with(['error'=> "Invalid email or Password!!"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not working. Throwing error - "Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance."

Comment: what is $user here?

Comment: @user9332352 can you please dd($checkLogin); ?

Answer (score 2):

In my case I used the authentication login command to make the laravel framework do the login system.
You are logged in as :

`{{ Auth::user()->name }}</div>`

Answer (score 0):

You've said `Auth::user()->name` doesn't work for you and that's you're keeping password as is without hashing it. Also, it looks like you're using multiple tables to store users. In this case, `Auth::check()`, `@guest`, `@auth` and other directives will not work for you.

You need to add a new a new guard, modify some Laravel code and login users manually. But since you're new to Laravel, I think the easier solution for you will be checking users manually:

```
$admin = DB::table('admin')->where(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])->first();
if (empty($admin)) {
    return redirect()->route('admin-login')->with('error', 'Invalid email or Password!');
}
```

You can also pass the variable to a view and share it between requests using session:

```
session(['user' => $admin]);
```

And do this instead of `@auth`:

```
if (session('user'))
```

And this instead of `@guest`:

```
if (empty(session('user')))
```

And to show admin name:

```
{{ session('user')->name }}
```

If you also want to avoid an error when there is no user, use the `optional()` helper:

```
{{ optional(session('user'))->name }}
```

It will print a name if a user is he is authenticated and will print nothing if he is not.

And I'd really recommend you to hash passwords with `brcypt()` helper and use one table for all users and just assign roles to the users. In this case, you'll be able to use built-in auth system and users' credentials will be safe.

Comment: i am not getting any error. but the user name is not showing. @guest part has been executed.

Comment: @user9332352 please let me know if it's working for you. I'm sure all other answers will not work if you're registering users using default method or using `bcrypt()` when creating a new user.

Comment: @user9332352 and it really looks like you're using default register method because you're doing `route('register')`

Comment: The session is working fine. problem is with the '@guest-else' tag in the view page. I need to use some if-else statement that would work. i hope this would help you in suggesting me the solution.

Comment: @user9332352 but you've said that my previous solution which is `auth()->user()->name` doesn't work. My question to you is do you store passwords in the table as something like `mypass145` or it's something like `$2y$10$UJitdozRrdn4JlcojBJgh.A.DRfjTr8Bv30uZRDR.iEJA5s1Q0od6`. Please check this.

Comment: i am not using any encryption. its mypass145.

Comment: @user9332352 if it is stored in DB as `mypass145` then my original solution `auth()->user()->name` was working. Why did you say that it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this in the controller:

```
return view('admin', ['name' => $checkLogin]);
```

Then in the views, you need to create a foreach loop:

```
@foreach($checkLogin as $key => $value)
    <p> {{ $value->email }} </p>
    <p> {{ $value->name }} </p>

@endforeach
```

Also, you can use this if you're using laravel's default auth:

```
{{ Auth::user()->name }}
```