# Laravel: Alternate to Session, to show logged in user data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to show logged in user data with the user of Laravel in-built class. I have used 'Session' to show the data which makes the code bulky and is not a good practice because we have to always put and flush data.

Here are my codes:

```
public function login(Request $req) {
    $this->validate($req, [
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    $email = $req->input('email');
    $password = $req->input('password');

    $checkLogin = DB::table('admin')->where(['email'=>$email,'password'=>$password])->first();

    if(count($checkLogin) > 0){
         Session::put('admin-name', $checkLogin->name);
         Session::put('admin-email', $checkLogin->email);
         Session::put('admin-address', $checkLogin->address);
         Session::put('admin-mobile',$checkLogin->mobile);
         Session::put('admin-dob',$checkLogin->dob);
         Session::put('admin-pic',$checkLogin->photo);
         Session::put('admin-password',$checkLogin->password);
         return view('admin');            
    }
    else {
       return Redirect::route('admin-login')->with(['error'=> "Invalid email or Password!!"]);
    }
}
```

View:

```html
<div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 round-img-neighbour">
    <p>{{Session::get('admin-name')}}</p>
    <small><cite title="">{{Session::get('admin-address')}} <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></i></cite></small>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually I dont very understand what thing that you are trying to achive. If you want minimize the database call, so it's not always querying data, may be what you need is `Cache`. With cache you also can set when the data should be expired.

Comment: I've tried to [explain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48822190/1227923) to you that you don't need to do all this stuff you're doing. You've reinvented the wheel so many times and you already have tons of problems the other developers just never meet because they're using Laravel built-in auth system. And you'll have a lot of problems in the future because you just don't listen. You're still reinventing the wheel, you're still keeping users passwords and not their hashes etc. Just use the standard auth system.

Answer (score 0):

So you are not logging in the admin:

First log him in then access his datas:

```
public function login(Request $req) {
    $this->validate($req, [
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    $email = $req->input('email');
    $password = $req->input('password');

    $checkLogin = DB::table('admin')->where(['email'=>$email,'password'=>$password])->first();

    if(count($checkLogin) > 0){

         $adminData = Auth::loginUsingId($checkLogin->id);

         return view('admin', compact('adminData'));            
    }
    else {
       return Redirect::route('admin-login')->with(['error'=> "Invalid email or Password!!"]);
    }
}
```

In view u may access like this:

```
<div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7 round-img-neighbour">
    <p>{{$adminData->admin-name}}</p>
    <small><cite title="">{{$adminData->admin-address}} <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></i></cite></small>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
Auth::user();
```

for get the logged in user information
for ex.

```
if(Auth::check())
{
    $loggedin_user = Auth::user();
}
```